# I am seeing authentication error in Tosca execution in jenkins for multiuser workspace

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd, tosca

I am setting up jenkins using a multiworkspace repository of Tosca and I am facing issue in authentication .The Same tests works fine in jenkins when i run through local workspace but when I run the tests in jenkins using multiuser workspace it doesnt run and throws error as above

The Tosca workspace works fine with Cmd execution with ToscaCIclient.exe using local workspace  .But it throws error when i try executing using multiuser workspace(The workspace is authenticated using SSO  and jenkins is installed as .msi file (and not as warfile)

2022-10-21 08:29:55,933  - Starting local execution
2022-10-21 08:29:55,933  - Configuration File Path:
2022-10-21 08:29:55,944  - Getting license...
2022-10-21 08:30:05,099  - Opening workspace: C:\Tosca_Projects\Tosca_Workspaces\S4H_STE_BPACT\S4H_STE_BPACT.tws
2022-10-21 08:30:08,389  - Open workspace failed
Inner Exception:
Tricentis.TCCore.Base.WorkspaceFileUnloadableException: Workspace

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am setting up jenkins using a multiworkspace repository of Tosca and I am facing issue in authentication .The Same tests works fine in jenkins  when i run through local workspace but when I run the tests in jenkins using multiuser workspace it doesnt run and throws error as above.Please help